# Updating Foreign Objects ORMLite - ANDROID

Tags: android, sql-update, foreign-key-relationship, cascade, ormlite

I want to know how can i update foreign objects in ORMLITE ?

Let's say i have these classes

**This is parent**

```
public static class Parent {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true,allowGeneratedIdInsert=true)
    int id;
    @DatabaseField
    String name;
    ...
```

**This is Child**

```
public static class Child{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId=true,allowGeneratedIdInsert=true)
    int id;
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true,foreignAutoCreate = true,foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnDefinition = "integer references parent(id) on update cascade")
    Parent parent;
    ...
```

Assume that we have these values:

**For Parent**
id=5
name = "big"

**For Child**
id=338
Parent = {id=5,name="big"}

Here when i want to update my parent id it is working good:

firstId=5, lastId=6

```
UpdateBuilder<Parent, Integer> builder = ParentDao.updateBuilder();
builder.where().eq("id", firstId);
builder.updateColumnValue("id", lastId);
builder.update();
```

After that, I am using select command to be sure that it is updated or not.  I'm sure it is updating for Parent.   But when I update my Parent id, I am losing parent object in my Child object. It is appearing like this:

**For Parent**
id=6
name = "big"

**For Child**
id=338
Parent = {null}

Does somebody know any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

***OrmLite does not auto-save nested objects automagically like other ORMs.***

So you need to update Child also.

---

Steps are

1. First you get the Parent object.
2. Read Child from that.
3. Update Parent
4. Now set updated parent to child
5. Update child also.

Comment: How can i update Child after updating Parent ? i can't use where command because in child, parent is null. Do you have any example for this ?

Comment: I think Emre is asking about update cascade and not about nested objects, I mean he is asking about database feature like on delete cascade which is working for him

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush And what I told :) I answered for the same. Isn't it?

Comment: Actually the idea of updating id is totally wrong , the id should not be Updated so Emre will not have problem if he didn't update the id

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush :) I didn't said about to update id. ORMlite doesn't support cascade insert/update/delete. You have to manage these. Thats why I added steps here..

Comment: How to Update 40 columns without using updateColumnValue in database ? Please suggest me.

Comment: @AnandSavjani Can you explain more about your problem? Better if your ask a separate question.

Comment: @PankajKumar : i am not able to ask separate question thats why i am asking my question here

Comment: @AnandSavjani Ok. Nop. Can you explain your problem in details?

Comment: @PankajKumar : I have 40 fields in table to update . But for update all fields i have to use updateColumnValue to update each and every column . Is there any way to update pojo or beab values directly without using updateColumnValue key and parameters ?

Comment: @AnandSavjani There is a way used into example code given by ORmlite, createOrUpdate. Look into that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91731/discussion-between-anand-savjani-and-pankaj-kumar).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how can i update foreign objects in ORMLITE ?

I may not be understanding the question but the proper way to do this is to just update the `child.parent` field like you would any other:

```
// child has a parent of #5
... child.getParent();

// update it with a new parent #6
Parent parent6 = new Parent(...);
// create the parent first so it gets an id
parentDao.create(parent6);
// set it on the child's field
child.setParent(parent6);
childDao.update(child);
```

This will update the fields of `child` in the database.  The `id` field from parent will be updated from 5 to 6.

If you need to update the `parent_id` field directly from 5 to 6 then you will need to refresh any existing `child` objects:

```
childDao.refresh(child);
```